# Insignificant typos in data in BigQuery

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery

I have some big json files, with each object on a new line. Something like this:

```
{"_id": "6047a8d", "type": ["Type1"], "service": ["5ae9595a"], "options": [{"name": "a", "value": false}, {"name": "b", "value": false}], "NameType": ["c"], "FakeNames": ["d", "e"], "text": "texts", "date": "2021-03-09T16:56:49.15Z"}
{"_id": "6047a", "type": ["Type1"], "service": ["5ae9595a9"], "options": [{"name": "abc", "value": false}, {"title": "def", "value": false}], "Nametype": ["xy"], "FakeNames": [], "text": "xyz", "date": "2021-03-09T17:02:20.976Z"}
```

This is the data that I have in Google Cloud and from which I create a table in BigQuery. However, sometimes a `[` bracket is randomly missing or instead of `"name": "some_string"` I have `"name": 2021`, which is an integer and therefore not in tune with the schema. I already have a Python code that cleaned the raw data and eliminated everything that BigQuery can't ingest, but I find it difficult and expensive to check for every missing bracket or to transform some integers into strings when these "mistakes" happen very rarely (only found two small mistakes in a folder of 10 such big documents).

How could I set, for example, a maximum number of bad records and what does it happen to these records?

Answer (score 0):

If you are crating a table from the csv file in GUI you have an option `Number of errors allowed`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I knew about this but do you know if there is any solution for json?